# Submitting score to GameCenter using RoboVM and libgdx

Tags: libgdx, robovm, game-center-leaderboard

I am using libgdx and robovm.

I get an error when I try to submit the score to the leaderboard on GameCenter on iOS. I am able to show the leaderboard. This is the error I get:

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'GKInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'A GKScore must specify a leaderboard.'
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException`

It is similar to this [SO-post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34143509/reporting-score-to-gamecenter-in-ios-9-xcode-7-1-1), but it is objective-c so I dont understand the answer.

This is my code for showing the leaderboard (this works)

```
public void getLeaderboardGPGS() {

    // If player is not authenticated, do nothing
    if (!GKLocalPlayer.getLocalPlayer().isAuthenticated()) {
        return;
    } 
    GKGameCenterViewController gameCenterView = new GKGameCenterViewController();

    gameCenterView.setGameCenterDelegate(new GKGameCenterControllerDelegateAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void didFinish (GKGameCenterViewController gameCenterViewController) {
            dismissViewControllerAndNotifyListener(gameCenterViewController, GKGameCenterViewControllerState.Leaderboards);
        }
    });
    gameCenterView.setViewState(GKGameCenterViewControllerState.Leaderboards);

    gameCenterView.setLeaderboardIdentifier(identifier);


    keyWindow.getRootViewController().presentViewController(gameCenterView, true, null);
}
```

This is my code for submiting the score (this does not work)

```
public void submitScoreGPGS(int score, MyLeaderBoardCallback callback) {

    // If player is not authenticated, do nothing
    if (!GKLocalPlayer.getLocalPlayer().isAuthenticated()) {
        //listener.scoreReportFailed(buildUnauthenticatedPlayerError());
        Gdx.app.log("Gamecenter","Notlogedin");
        return;
    }
    GKScore scoreReporter = new GKScore(identifier);

    scoreReporter.setValue(score);
    scoreReporter.setLeaderboardIdentifier(identifier);
    //scoreReporter.setShouldSetDefaultLeaderboard(true);
    //scoreReporter.setContext(0);

    NSArray<GKScore> scores = new NSArray<GKScore>(scoreReporter);

    Gdx.app.log("Gamecenter","Report socre");
    GKScore.reportScores(scores, new VoidBlock1<NSError>() {
        @Override
        public void invoke (NSError error) {
            if (error != null) {
                Gdx.app.log("Gamecenter","scorereportfailed");
            } else {
                Gdx.app.log("Gamecenter","scorereportcompleted");
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Anyone knows what the problem might be? I have tried googleing but there is little information about "robovm and gamekit/gamecenter".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable that contained the leaderboard id was garbage collected for some reason. Had to hard-code the string at `scoreReporter.setLeaderboardIdentifier("my hard coded id");` . Weird....